# What happens when a character has both Superior Will and is wearing a Circlet of Arkhosia?

Tags: dnd-4e

The Circlet of Arkhosia grants:

> Property: When you are dazed or stunned, you can make a saving throw against one of those conditions at the start of your turn. If you save, you can act normally on your turn. If you fail, you can make another saving throw against the effect at the end of your turn.

The feat Superior Will grants:

> In addition, if you are dazed or stunned, you can make a saving throw at the start of your turn to end that effect, even if the effect doesn’t normally end on a save.

Is there any real benefit from taking both the feat and the item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The circlet allows a save against **one** stun or daze effect.

The feat appears to allow saves against **all** stun or daze effects.

Depending on your reading of the circlet, it may allow saves against non-save ends effects, and if it does so, it actually allows two such saves.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out. Cause double-saves seem against the intent of the rules.

Comment: By double saves are you referring to a save from each effect at the start of your turn, or are you referring to my observation that the circlet alone could allow you to try to make two saves (one at the start of turn and one at the end of turn) against an effect that does not normally allow a save to end?

Answer (score 2):

Superior Will lets you save against daze or stun effects that last until the end of the enemy's next turn, which can be a huge advantage. If your DM uses lots of enemies with daze and stun effects, this sounds like a good investment, particularly if you don't have bonuses to your saves (e.g. the feats Stubborn Survivor and Human Perseverance). So even if you don't make your saves as easily as other characters, the circlet will give you two chances against daze and stun effects a save will normally end.

On the other hand, if you do have bonuses to your saves, I think the circlet is a little redundant. There may be more attractive Head slot items depending on your build.

To answer the original question, a character with Superior Will who wears a circlet of Arkhosia may make one saving throw against a daze or stun effect at the start of his turn even if the effect doesn't normally end on a save.

If the effect does normally end on a save and the character fails the save at the start of the turn, he may make another saving throw against the effect at the end of his turn as normal.

If the effect does not normally end on a save, e.g. it lasts until the end of the enemy's next turn, the character does not get to make another saving throw against the effect at the end of his turn.

Comment: Do you have anything to cite regarding this? I.e. why wouldn't you get two saving throws at the start of your turn?

Comment: Sorry, I was talking specifically about whether the character gets a saving throw at the end of his turn versus an effect that doesn't normally end on a save. You're right that the character would get two saving throws at the start of his turn.